# Can anyone provide a proof of this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, binomial-theorem

I was recently studying exponential and logarithmic series on Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight. While reading it I encountered a solved example:—

> **To expand $\log _{e}(1+x)$ in ascending powers of $x$.**
>
> Let us suppose $e^c=a$, so that $c=\log _{e} a$; by substituting for c we obtain
>
> $a^{y}=1+y \log _{e} a+\frac{y^{2}\left(\log _{e} a\right)^{2}}{2 !}+\frac{y^{3}\left(\log _{e} a\right)^{3}}{3 !}+\ldots$
>
> In this series write $1+x$ for $a$; thus
>
> $(1+x)^{y}=1+y \log _{e}(1+x)+\frac{y^{2}}{2 !}\left\{\log _{e}(1+x)\right\}^{2}+\frac{y^{3}}{3 !}\left\{\log _{e}(1+x)\right\}^{3}+\text{              }\ldots .(1)$
>
> Also by Binomial Theorem when $x<1$ we have
>
> $(1+x)^{y}=1+y x+\frac{y(y-1)}{2 !} x^{2}+\frac{y(y-1)(y-2)}{3 !} x^{3}+\text{               }\ldots .(2)$
>
> Now in $(2)$ the coefficient of y is
>
> $x+\frac{(-1)}{1 \cdot 2} x^{2}+\frac{(-1)(-2)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3} x^{3}+\frac{(-1)(-2)(-3)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4} x^{4}+\ldots$
>
> That is, $x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\frac{x^{4}}{4}+\ldots$
>
> Equate this to the coefficient of y in $(1)$; thus we have
>
> $\log _{e}(1+x)=x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\frac{x^{4}}{4}+\ldots$

**Can anyone please explain me how in this *"Now in $(2)$ the coefficient of y is"* step the coefficient of $y$ is found to be the series given below?**

$x+\frac{(-1)}{1 \cdot 2} x^{2}+\frac{(-1)(-2)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3} x^{3}+\frac{(-1)(-2)(-3)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4} x^{4}+\ldots$

**Can anyone provide a proof of this?**

*Any help would be appreciated.*

Edit:— Thanks to AkivaWeinberger for explaining me.

In the later articles the book is repeatedly stating about the coefficient of $y^2$ without showing what it is or how it is to be found out.

**Can anyone please show me how to find the coefficient of$y^2$ from (2)?**

Comment: What's the coefficient of $y$ in $y(y-1)(y-2)/3!$?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger 2/3!

Comment: Yes. Another way to write that is $(-1)(-2)/(1\cdot2\cdot3)$.

Comment: If we expand $\dfrac{y(y-1)(y-2)}{3!}$ into a polynomial, we get $\dfrac1{3!}y^3-\dfrac3{3!}y^2+\dfrac2{3!}y$. Putting $y=0$ would give us $0$. But since there's no constant term, we can divide by $y$ to get another polynomial and then substitute $0$

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Oh thanks you very much. This a kind of new trick to find coefficient for me.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Hey, Can we divide any term without an equation by some variable/value like you did in this case like you divided $\dfrac1{3!}y^3-\dfrac3{3!}y^2+\dfrac2{3!}y$ by $y$.? Putting $y$ directly as 0 gives 0. So, it's kind of counterintuitive.

Comment: I'm kind of dividing by $0$ (dividing by $y$ and then setting $y=0$) but you can justify that by saying I'm taking a limit or something similar

Comment: I think the author did the same thing but he didn't explain it. Anyway thanks a lot for sharing this technique.